# Restoring OpenPGP Keys from an Ubuntu Backup

Tags: ssh, thunderbird, public-key, private-key, openpgp

My computer with *Ubuntu* broke and have a backup from that (*Déjá Dup*). Now i want to restore my **public and private keys** to a *Thunderbird* installation in *Windows 8*.

There's this **.ssh** folder inside the Ubuntu home folder. **Are my keys there?**

Inside the .ssh folder there are the following files:

- id_rsa
- id_rsa.pub
- id_rsa_backup
- id_rsa_backup.pub
- A config and a known_host file.

When importing keys from file in *OpenPGP* an Alert says:
**"Importing the keys failed"**

Renamed id_rsa to id_rsa.asc. Same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some keys in your `~/.ssh` folder - but definitively not the ones you're looking for: These are for SSH authentication. The key's you're looking for are stored in your `~/.gnupg` folder, namely

- `~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg` for your public keys
- `~/.gnupg/secring.gpg` for your private keys

With Thunderbird, you're probably using Enigmail for OpenPGP encryption. Enigmail also uses GnuPG, so you can possibly just drop all that files in your new GnuPG folder (if you're overwriting anything, make sure you're not loosing any keys! If you're not sure where this folder is on your windows installation, run `gpg --version` which also dumps the GnuPG home directory.

Comment: Thanks Jens.

I dropped all the files from .gnupg to gnupg.
Now i can read the encrypted mail and the recipients confirmed they get my key properly.
I still getting this error when trying to read my sent messeges:
"Error - secret key needed to decrypt message"

Comment: Found out how to read my sent messages:
OpenPGP Preferences > Sending > Add my own key to the recipients list (checked).